# get set method for value in class

Tags: apex, visualforce, debug, getter, setter

I have a class with a getter and setter method. Could anyone explain how this works. If I am correct it is suppose to get and set a variable between a visualforce page and apex class. Is this also possible between 2 apex classes?. I am trying to debug a class with the following:

`String alphaClauseStr {get; set;}`

But i cant seem to find the alphaClauseStr in the visualforce page, could this be somewhere else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This variable is using the default access, `private`. You won't be able to "see" it outside of the class it is defined in or in a Visualforce page. If you want to be able to use it in Visualforce or another class, you should use the `public` access modifier:

```
public String alphaClauseStr;
```

If you're not using it in Visualforce, there is no semantic difference between the version above and this version:

```
public String alphaClauseStr { get; set; }
```

You'll want to read more in [Access Modifiers](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_access_modifiers.htm), [`@TestVisible` Annotation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_annotation_testvisible.htm), and [Apex Properties](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_properties.htm).

Comment: @sfdcfox Thanks for the answer. I read trough the documents but still have 2 things which are not clear 1. Does this mean in my example that the variable is only visible in the current class so why use get/set. 2 Is it possible to have a private get/set and that a public value from an VFP is passed to this class with the private modifier?

Comment: @Jenssen (1) It's allowed, but there's no purpose to it. It's semantically the same. (2) Private members can't be directly accessed, but you could use a getter/setter, like this: `private String someValue; public String getSomeValue() { return someValue; } public void setSomeValue(String value) { someValue = value; }` You would access it in your page as `{!someValue}` (the getter and setter will be called as appropriate).